# Bootstrap 4 - alterar carousel indicators para texto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou usando Bootstrap 4 e eu não posso mudar o indicador para aparecer o texto em relação ao item. Eu tentei algumas opções de outras respostas do StackOverflow mas nenhuma funcionou, se alguém poder dar um exemplo de código funcionando, agradeço. 
**Nota:** Eu estou usando Sass com webpack.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="0" class="active">text1</li>
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="1">text 1</li>
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="2">text 2</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
          <h5>Text 1</h5>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
         <h5>Text 2</h5>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev" data-interval="4000">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next" data-interval="4000">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi... onde tem as Setas vc quer mudar por texto? Tipo no lugar da seta da direita colocar "próximo" e da esquerda "anterior" é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas caso vc quera "esconder" as Setinha, e mostrar apenas o texto vc precisa mudar o elemento que vai receber a classe `.sr-only` uma vez que esse classe ser para "esconder" elementos na tela, porém deixas os elementos visíveis para os *Screen Readers* (SR) leitores de tela.

Veja as propriedade da classe `sr-only`

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Repare que essa classe foi feita para o usuário comum não conseguir vê-la na tela, porém deixa o elemento acessível para os *Screen Readers*. Aqui vc confere a documentação oficial sobre isso: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/screenreaders/

---

Então para resolver o problema basta remover a classe `.sr-only` do `span` que tem o texto e colocar o atributo `hidden` no `span` das setas.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide bg-primary" data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="0" class="active">text1</li>
                <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="1">text 1</li>
                <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="2">text 2</li>
            </ul>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                    <h5>Text 1</h5>
                    <p>
                        text ...
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        text ...
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
                    <h5>Text 2</h5>
                    <p>
                        text ...
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        text ...
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev" data-interval="4000">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" hidden></span>
                <span class="">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next" data-interval="4000">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" hidden></span>
                <span class="">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Dica1:** Nessa resposta tem uns detalhes a mais sobre o atributo Hidden [Usar "left: -9999px" ao invés de "display: none"? Mas por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257153/usar-left-9999px-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-display-none-mas-por-qu%C3%AA)

**Dica2:** Documentação Mozilla sobre o atributo Hidden https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden