# Uppercase HTML vs CSS

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre usar `text-transform: uppercase` no CSS e usar letras maiúsculas direto no HTML.

- Existe alguma diferença entre os 2?
- Qual o mais recomendado?

Comment: Você se refere a propriedade `text-transform` do CSS?

Comment: Exatamente! vou editar a pergunta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Era bom pesquisar também se isso afeta de alguma forma a parte semântica de acessibilidade, se os leitores de tela interpretam letras maiúsculas do CSS ou do HTML.

Comment: Sim, acho que leitores de tela reconhecem o HTML, sendo assim, como o CSS só aplica estilo, ele seria o mais recomendado, por que os leitores podem reconhecer de maneira errada o texto no HTML, quando maiúsculos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exitem uma diferença básica. **O CSS só altera o aspecto visual.**

Se vc tiver um `input` com `text-transform: uppercase`, na hora que vc fizer o `submit` desse form, o texto dentro do `input` vai com o texto original, ou seja, se o usuário escrever em caixa baixa, e o CSS colocar em caixa alta, o texto vai ser enviado em letras minúsculas, mesmo na tela do usuário o texto aparecendo em caixa alta.

```css
input {
    text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
Esse input sempre vai mostrar a letra em UPPERCASE, mas se o usuário escrever em minúsculo, na hora do submit vai ser enviado em minúsiculo, mesmo na interfaçe o texto aparecendo em caixa alta<br>
<input type="text" name="" id="">
```

---

**Sobre a Semântica**

Sobre a semântica é preciso ter em mente que o CSS só altera estilo, e o leitor de tela não sabe se o texto é vermelho ou preto, ou se está em Arial ou Times. O ideal é que vc use as tag semânticas do HTML como `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<cite>`, `<q>`, , etc da forma correta para agregar algum valor para o texto que está entre as tags. Isso vai ajudar ao leitor de tela a interpretar o texto. Mesmo o `display:none` usado pelo CSS as vezes não é o suficiente para esconder um elemento do Screen Reader ([leia sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257153/usar-left-9999px-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-display-none-mas-por-qu%C3%AA)), por isso o HTML tem o atributo [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), para que o leitor ignore o elemento que tem esse atributo. *Acredito ser improvável que leitores de tela considerem o CSS na semântica. Até mesmo o conteúdo de texto no `content` de um pseudo-elemento é ignorado no DOM e vc não consegue acesa-lo.*

---

**Sobre o SEO**

Não tenho dados nem experiência para comprovar nada nesse ponto, e como o Google vai indexar `INSS` ou `<span style="text-transform:uppercase">inss</span>`. O mecanismo de busca é obscuro, e o indicado é vc fazer um `Teste A/B` para ver como ele trata isso. já se vc colocar `<strong style="text-transform:uppercase">inss</strong>` ai sim vc vai dar um valor semântico que pode influencia no resultado da pesquisa. Mas como falei, só testando para saber, e mesmo assim o Google vive mudando essas regras... Mas por outro lado, sabemos que o Google reconhece o CSS, e inclusive leva ele em conta para qualificar o seu site, e esse é mais um motivo do assunto ser obscuro...

Answer (score 6):

Existem diferenças, são muito importantes e recomenda-se utilizar aquele que faz sentido para o seu propósito; eles não são equivalentes.

Algo que você precisa **sempre** tem em mente: **CSS aplica estilos**. Você precisa deixar o texto em caixa alta porque ele deve ser caixa alta ou é meramente visual? Se fazer parte do significado do texto, ele deve estar em caixa alta já no HTML; se for meramente visual, aplique o estilo com CSS.

Ao escrever uma sigla, por exemplo, você deverá colocá-la em caixa alta diretamente no HTML, pois, por convenção, toda sigla deve estar em caixa alta - faz parte do sentido do texto ser assim. Porém, se você deseja apenas, por questões de estilo, deixar o texto em caixa alta, talvez para melhorar a legibilidade, você deve fazer isso com CSS - estar em caixa alta não faz parte do sentido do text.

**Exemplo de siglas**

```html
<p>Você não deve utilizar <mark>CSS</mark> para deixar siglas, como <mark>HTML</mark>, em caixa alta</p>
```

**Exemplo de texto em caixa alta por legibilidade**

```css
li.title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">Menu</li>
  <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Anderson. Vi também que é recomendado (com exceção das siglas) usar o text-transform do CSS, por conta dos leitores de tela. Leitores não reconhecem palavras inteiras quando estão em maiúsculas no HTML, mas como no text-transform só é alterado o estilo, o leitor consegue ler normalmente o texto na pagina.

Answer (score 2):

Usando diretamente letras maiúsculas no HTML, certamente você economizaria na tarefa do browser de ter que renderizar a regra CSS. Mas creio que essa diferença de tempo de renderização é muito irrelevante.

Outro ponto é se o texto que você vai aplicar a regra `text-transform: uppercase` precisará ser alterado — talvez por algum script — e neste caso faz sentido usar o `text-transform`, por ser mais fácil de alterar apenas uma regra CSS ao invés de ter que trocar todo o texto.

Answer (score 1):

CSS neste caso irá alterar apenas o que o usuário esta vendo.

A diferença estará no dia em que os dados coletados necessitarem de ser enviados em UPPERCASE.

Como o CSS vai alterar somente o que o usuário esta visualizando e não o que esta sendo enviado, poderá ter erros.

No segundo caso o mais correto seria usar javascript ou jquery para gerar o UPPERCASE, desta maneira os dados enviados realmente estarão em UPPERCASE.

Comment: Valeu, Wemerson!

Comment: Ok, mano thanks